# Need to run GlassFish server using Netbeans

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9, tomcat

I am using netbeans 6.9.1 with glassFish server.I created a web application with glassfish server. while running the application, its running in address http://localhost:29927/. But i want to view my application in browser in the address http://vigneshsr (vigneshsr is my computer name). How to do it,where to change the port number in glassfish (as we do it in apache tomcat).Guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure glassfish using the admin web gui at http://localhost:4848

Here you can configure your network listeners to change the port etc.

If you want to use a different address on your local system, you'll need to configure your hosts file, this link explains how to do this:- [Edit Hosts File](http://support.ecenica.com/domain-names/edit-hosts-file-mac-windows/)